# Why Solr's facet command is not found?

Tags: solr, lucene, faceted-search

I was learning Solr with the QuickStart(http://lucene.apache.org/solr/quickstart.html).
But when I try to use facet command like the QuickStart :

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?wt=json&indent=true&q=*:*&rows=0 \
                                              &facet=true&facet.field=manu_id_s
In your terminal, you'll see:

{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":3,
    "params":{
      "facet":"true",
      "indent":"true",
      "q":"*:*",
      "facet.field":"manu_id_s",
      "wt":"json",
      "rows":"0"}},
  "response":{"numFound":2990,"start":0,"docs":[]
  },
  "facet_counts":{
    "facet_queries":{},
    "facet_fields":{
      "manu_id_s":[
        "corsair",3,
        "belkin",2,
        "canon",2,
        "apple",1,
        "asus",1,
        "ati",1,
        "boa",1,
        "dell",1,
        "eu",1,
        "maxtor",1,
        "nor",1,
        "uk",1,
        "viewsonic",1,
        "samsung",0]},
    "facet_dates":{},
    "facet_ranges":{},
    "facet_intervals":{}}}
```

Then I input the command:

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?wt=json&indent=true&q=*:*&rows=0&facet=true&facet.field=manu_id_s
```

in terminal,but what I get is:

`[1] 1058
     [2] 1060
     [3] 1061
     [4] 1062
     [5] 1063
     {"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":0,"params":{"wt":"json"}},"response": {"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]}}
     facet.field=manu_id_s：command not found
     [1]   done           curl http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?wt=json
     [2]   done                  indent=true
     [3]   done                  q=*:*
     [4]-  done                  rows=0
     [5]+  done                  facet=on`

Why the facet command is not found?

Comment: did you miss the question mark after /select ?

Comment: sorry,it's just a editing error.I have modified the description.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?wt=json&indent=true&q=*:*&rows=0&facet=true&facet.field=manu_id_s'
```

You just missed quotation marks in URL :D

Comment: Thank you!I will follow your advise.